# React: Applying box-sizing to all elements via styled-components in react

Tags: styled-components

How can I add the following styling to my JavaScript using **styled-components**?

```
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .cf:before,
  .cf:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
  }

  .cf:after {
    clear: both;
  }
```

Comment: are you asking about [`createGlobalStyle`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.